# mysql Match up two tables using two columns with different value presentation

Tags: mysql

I have two table that I want to match up
The goal is to find which ad is available for which agent based on gender:

```
table 'agents' has (gender, name,agent_id).
table 'ads' has (ad_id,gender_id, ad_name).
```

Need to create a matching table/view/select that has (ad_id,viewer_id).

```
viewer.gender could be 'FEMALE' or 'MALE'
ads.gender_ID could be '1' stands for both , '2' stands for FEMALE and '3' stands for 'MALE'
```

I could do this on application level but I ultimately want to have a query so I can create view/table and update it every day.
Thanks guys.

Comment: What is the Viewer_Id column? Missing a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ad_id, agent_id
from agents
join ads on gender_id = 1 or gender_id = (if (gender = 'FEMALE', 2, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a join.  The relation is just a bit more complicated than for a typical join:

```
select ad.ad_id, ag.agent_id as viewer_id
from ads ad join
     agents ag
     on (ad.gender_id in (1, 2) and ag.gender = 'FEMALE') or
        (ad.gender_id in (1, 3) and ag.gender = 'MALE')
```

This will not be efficient on largish tables.  If that is a problem, then normalize the genders to they are consistent in the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

This is "half-way-normalization". Alter table "agents", add a field "gender_id", make an update on the table  like `... set gender_id = 1 where gender = 'FEMALE* ...` , drop field "gender" and feel happy.